# SelectionChanged not triggered when using ItemTemplate in Silverlight 3 ComboBox

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0, combobox, itemtemplate

I'm experiencing som strange behaviour by the Silverlight ComboBox.  I started out with some simple code:

xaml:

```
<ComboBox Name="drpInstallation" SelectionChanged="drpInstallation_SelectionChanged" />
```

cs:

```
List<string> installations = new List<string>();
installations.Add("Testing 123");
installations.Add("Antoher test");
installations.Add("Yeah");
drpInstallation.ItemsSource = installations;
```

Everything works well when clicking an item.  However, if I use the ItemTemplate in ComboBox like this:

xaml:

```
<ComboBox Name="drpInstallation" SelectionChanged="drpInstallation_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Installation}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

cs:

```
ICollection<InstallationClass> installations = a list of the installation class;
drpInstallation.ItemsSource = installations;
```

InstallationClass.cs:

```
public class InstallationClass
{
    public int PK;
    public string Installation;
}
```

Now the ComboBox displays correctly, however when I click the **text** if the items nothing happens.  If I click just right of the text itself then the item is selected like normal.  Point is; the natural thing to do is to click the text itself, not to the left or right of it.  Any idea why this happens, and any idea how to correct it?  Is this a Silverlight bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DataTemplate should look like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="drpInstallation" SelectionChanged="drpInstallation_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Installation}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The problem was that ComboBoxItems consume the click event, rather than bubbling it up.

Comment: I've rewritten code to bypass this problem, I'll however set this as the accepted solution as it seems kind of logical ;)